# How can I enable only Q-Swash in Fontspec?

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, opentype

I am using the 'Minion 3' font with `fontspec` using `XeLaTeX`.  I would like to enable the alternate glyph for Q, which fontforge tells me is called Q.swash, in the font face Minion 3 Italic.

If I add `swsh` to the `RawFeature` paramater of `setmainfont`, I can enable swashes globally.  However, I don't like most of the italic swashes, and want to enable **only ** `Q.swash`.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is there a stylistic alternative defined for that?

Comment: If all else fails, you could define `\Q`, e.g. as `{\minionslash Q}\relax` Or set the character active, although that might not be the best idea.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t have Minion 3 for testing, but if you’re willing to use `luatex`, something like this should work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua{
  fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
    name = "qqqq",
    type = "alternate",
    data =
    {
      Q = "Q.swash",
    },
  }
}
\setmainfont{Minion 3}[ItalicFeatures={RawFeature=+qqqq}]
\begin{document}
\itshape This Is a Quality Font.
\end{document}
```